# How to add the years in xAxis date format while exporting? Also how to add the data source during the exporting?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highcharts

I want to add the years in **xAxis** scale while exporting the options. I tried this code, its working fine in **jsfiddle** but not in my local.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        exporting: {
            chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'export Title'
                },
                 xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                            millisecond: '%b %e %Y',
                            second: '%b %e %Y',
                            minute: '%b %e %Y',
                            hour: '%b %e %Y',
                            day: '%b %e %Y',
                            week: '%b %e %Y',
                            month: '%b %e %Y',
                            year: '%b %e %Y'
                        }
                    },
            },
            scale: 3,
            fallbackToExportServer: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Offline export'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the button to download as PNG/SVG'
        },  
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        xAxis: {
           type:'dateTime'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 126.0, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Also I tried to add the data sources in the exporting options, is there any solution for this.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aautkqrg/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure exported chart by [chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions)